# How to aggregate if the

Tags: django, templates, sum, aggregate

In django template I could access the price with `{% for x in done %}` and then access the the product, which is a foreign key to a table about products. So I access the price of the product like this `{{x.productt.omzet}}`.

My question is: How can I sum them up?

In views.py I successfully used the aggregate function to sum values from a child table; however, in this case I need to aggregate values from a grand child table. I failed to do that in a for loop at views.py.

```
def factuur(request, id):
factuur = Factuur.objects.get(id=id)
leerling = Leerling.objects.get(name=factuur.leerling)
jezelf = Leerling.objects.get(id=2)
paid = BankTransactions.objects.filter(actor=factuur.leerling)
total_paid = paid.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
done = Product.objects.filter(leerling=factuur.leerling)
total_done = done.aggregate(Sum('productt'))

if leerling.status == 4:
    bedrag1 = "done - paid = factuur"
elif leerling.status == 3:
    bedrag1 = "factuur is any"
else:
    bedrag1 = "factuur is niet van toepassing"
notice = bedrag1

context = {'factuur': factuur,
           'leerling': leerling,
           'jezelf': jezelf,
           'paid': paid,
           'done': done,
           'total_paid': total_paid,
           'total_done': total_done,
           'notice': notice,
           }
return render(request, 'rozendale/factuur.html', context)
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Bedrag</th>
                </tr>
                {% for x in done %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/item/{{x.id}}">{{x.date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/product/{{x.productt.id}}">{{x.productt.name}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{x.productt.omzet}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
               {% endfor %}
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Totaal:</th>
                    <td>
                    {{total_done}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                    <th>Factuur</th>
                    <th>Betaald</th>
                </tr>
                {% for x in paid %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/item/{{x.id}}">{{x.date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/factuur/{{x.factuur.id}}">{{x.factuur}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{x.amount}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
               {% endfor %}
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Totaal:</th>
                    <td>{{total_paid.amount__sum}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
def factuur(request, id):
factuur = Factuur.objects.get(id=id)
leerling = Leerling.objects.get(name=factuur.leerling)
yourself= Leerling.objects.get(id=2)

paid = BankTransactions.objects.filter(actor=factuur.leerling)
total_paid = []
for pay in paid:
    total_paid += [(pay.amount)]
total_paid = sum(total_paid)

done = Product.objects.filter(leerling=factuur.leerling)
total_done = []
for les in done:
    dit = ProductName.objects.get(id=les.productt_id)
    total_done += [(dit.omzet)]
total_done = sum(total_done)

openstaand = total_done - total_paid
#notice = factuur.amount * factuur.productt.omzet

if leerling.status == 4:
    notice = openstaand
elif leerling.status == 3:
    notice = factuur.amount * factuur.productt.omzet
else:
    notice = "factuur is niet van toepassing"

context = {'factuur': factuur,
           'leerling': leerling,
           'yourself': yourself,
           'paid': paid,
           'done': done,
           'openstaand': openstaand,
           'total_paid': total_paid,
           'total_done': total_done,
           'notice': notice,
           }
return render(request, 'test/factuur.html', context)
```

Factuur = invoice. This is a detail-view of an invoice (`object..get(id=id)`). That invoice belongs to one customer, but to many products and to many transactions. In this code I filtered all of them that belong to that customer. I did that with the for loop. Then in the for loop I iterate over the filtered products and transactions of the customer. In each iteration I use the GET method to get the price of the product. But that price is in another table: The table of products(details). So actually, that price of the product is from a grandchild table.

Comment: I edited the answer by putting the entire function from views.py. The challenge was to sum the prices of products per customer because those prices were in a seperate table.